# R find max date per ID and create filed with maximum vale of another fild for the max date

Tags: r, na

I am trying to create a field (maxKat) which fills the values based on another column which is based on the maximum date.

A sample code:

```
a=c("RM", "kat", "Month")
RM=c("c1234","c1234","c1234", "c12345")
kat=as.integer(c("103","101","102", "145"))
Month=as.integer(c("201710","201711","201712", "201710"))
test=data.frame(RM,kat,Month)
names(test)=a


test2=aggregate(test[c("Month")], by=list(test$RM), max)
names(test2)=c("RM", "Monthmax")

test=merge(test,test2, by="RM")
test$maxkat=ifelse(test$Month==test$Monthmax, test$kat, NA)
```

Here I am calculating the maximum date and then merged back into the main dataset (test). I want to create a new fild named maxkat witch takes the maximu value of kat based in the condifum the date matches the maxdate.

The results is as follows:

```
      RM kat  Month Monthmax maxkat
1  c1234 103 201710   201712     NA
2  c1234 101 201711   201712     NA
3  c1234 102 201712   201712    102
4 c12345 145 201710   201710    145
```

Any feedback is much appreciated on how to fill teh Nulls with the desired value.

The desired result for the whole dataset is:

```
      RM kat  Month Monthmax maxkat
1  c1234 103 201710   201712    102
2  c1234 101 201711   201712    102
3  c1234 102 201712   201712    102
4 c12345 145 201710   201710    145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired result:

```
RM=c("c1234","c1234","c1234", "c12345")
kat=as.integer(c("103","101","102", "145"))
Month=as.integer(c("201710","201711","201712", "201710"))
test=data.frame(RM,kat,Month)


test2=aggregate(test["Month"], by=list(test$RM), max)
names(test2)=c("RM", "Monthmax")
test2$maxkat <- test$kat[test$Month == test2$Monthmax]
(test=merge(test,test2, by="RM"))
#       RM kat  Month Monthmax maxkat
# 1  c1234 103 201710   201712    102
# 2  c1234 101 201711   201712    102
# 3  c1234 102 201712   201712    102
# 4 c12345 145 201710   201710    145
```

The strategy here is to add the maxkat variable to the test2 data frame before merging, and base it on the value of `test$kat` when `test$Month` is equal to `test2$Monthmax`.  You're comparing values between data frames of different dimensions, but because `test2` was created exactly by finding the maximum value for Month, you'll get exactly the right length object to put in test2. THEN you merge it back into test.